# Random Forest with categorical Data is predicting only Data within one Category

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Im using scikit learn's RandomForrestRegressor and I cannot make it work or at least it seems like it. 
The Data that I am using has categorical data which I encodedd with the LabelBinarizer so my data looks like this:

```
Id     Cat1 Cat2 Cat3 .... Cat50 
123    0    1    0         0 
...
```

Each row can only have one of the given categories. 
Now I train my model with the given ratings for each item, which is numerical with scikit-learns RandomForrestRegressor.
My y is a rating.
My X are the features of the item containing the categories.
So my y and X looks something like this:

```
y = [0,1,1,4,,3,7,8,1,9]

X = [[0, 1, 0, ..., 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0...,0]
    ...]
```

I want to predict the rating y on new items based on the item data arrays in X. For this I use the RandomForrestRegressor like this:

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=60000, random_state=0, max_depth=100)
        regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
        theta[user_id] = regressor.feature_importances_
```

I chose the max-depth=106 as there are 100 item features and n_estimator=60000 as I have around 30000 items. But I am not quite sure if the n_estimator is chosen wisely and even if I choose the n_estimator very low, the results remain the same.
I multiply each item feature with the theta entry for the user where I store the feature importance.
The result for the best fitting items for the user looks as follows:

```
Id Name    Category  
12 example Cat1
34 example Cat1
56 example Cat1
..
```

So every prediction has the same category altough there are for example 50 different categories and the training data does contain a lot more than cat1 samples. In fact Cat1 is a small part of the sample.

My question is how do I determine where my error is? Should I consider this to be an error as this result cannot be reasonable in my case. Which next step should I take to determine where the error lies?

Comment: It could be that your data is highly unbalanced (the class which is being predicted is the largest part of your data so model predicts only label of that class). As for estimators, I dont think you should need that many, if it model does not work for ~100 estimators, increasing their number will likely not lead to any better results

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, @Ach113. I will change my n_estimators then. The classes might be slightly unbalanced. What is the best way to deal with it using a random forrest?

Comment: Some things are unclear to me: you got 50 categories of which each user can have 1. You say that the model returns "category 1" always. So you do want to predict for each example which category it is? If so based on what features do you want to do that? It cant be the categories you want to predict. Maybe give a clear example of what the features are and what value you want to predict and why that can be "cat1". There seems to be some confusion. ;)

Comment: @ElmarMacek Thank you for the reply! I want to predict a rating for unseen items for a user u. Each item can have only one category. I dont want to predict the category of the item. I will update my question with further information.

Answer (score 1):

What are your input features?

You should check if it is an imbalanced dataset:
`df['Cat1'].sum` `df['Cat2'].sum`
Probably it will be:

```
Cat1   Cat2 ... Cat50
10000   4        3
```

This would mean that your data is imbalanced. You then really need to check what techniques you can use, some names are: under- and oversammpling, or isolation forest.

Are you sure you want to use regression? And not classification? Check this package out: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

And this should give you an idea what problem you want to solve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning

Comment: Thank you, @PV8, I will check my data again and proof if I can use some tools to remove the imbalance in the data. 
My input features are the categories.
I am sure I want to use regression as my hypothesis is not a class but a numerical value. A classifier does not make sense if the output is a numerical value, right? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Yes, but somehow I don't get it what you want to predict

Answer (score 1):

If unbalanced data is your problem I suggest checking out [imblearn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) library, it has some functions that allow balancing the data, for example Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique ([SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html)) allows 'upsampling' the data by creating extra instances of minority classes for training and its super simple to use.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE()
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

Then you can validate your model on the original data.